# jq join function is not working as expected

Tags: jq

I am executing jq using join but it is not working as expected. Could you pls help?

The input is -

```
[
    [
        {
            "InstID": "i-049c7aa5976d78ab3",
            "Name": "dr-psoft-report01",
            "ImageID": "ami-09a868b800080436e",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "OS": "Windows",
            "InstType": "z1d.large",
            "CpuCore": 1,
            "ThreadsPerCore": 2,
            "VolID": [
                "vol-07498f95efef04f85"
            ],
            "PrivIP": "10.77.132.218",
            "Status": "stopped"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "InstID": "i-05831bbd78bcfb9ac",
            "Name": "dr-psoft-web01",
            "ImageID": "ami-09a868b800080436e",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "OS": "Windows",
            "InstType": "t3.xlarge",
            "CpuCore": 2,
            "ThreadsPerCore": 2,
            "VolID": [
                "vol-0b9390e079150ac1c",
                "vol-0cd2df67aa096af52",
                "vol-090c0d3290e1c4dad"
            ],
            "PrivIP": "10.77.132.170",
            "Status": "stopped"
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            "InstID": "i-0a6ef93417cc064eb",
            "Name": "dr-psoft-app01",
            "ImageID": "ami-09a868b800080436e",
            "Architecture": "x86_64",
            "OS": "Windows",
            "InstType": "z1d.xlarge",
            "CpuCore": 2,
            "ThreadsPerCore": 2,
            "VolID": [
                "vol-00a5285f92f18b9ee",
                "vol-0b979d1b578a1d672"
            ],
            "PrivIP": "10.77.132.139",
            "Status": "stopped"
        }
    ],
]
```

I am executing below jq command -

```
jq -r '.[] | .[] | [.InstID, .Name, .ImageID, .Architecture, .OS, .InstType, (.CpuCore|tostring), (.ThreadsPerCore|tostring), .PrivIP, .Status, ((.VolID[]|[.])|join(","))] | join("|")'
```

But the output is -

```
i-049c7aa5976d78ab3|dr-psoft-report01|ami-09a868b800080436e|x86_64|Windows|z1d.large|1|2|10.77.132.218|stopped|vol-07498f95efef04f85
i-05831bbd78bcfb9ac|dr-psoft-web01|ami-09a868b800080436e|x86_64|Windows|t3.xlarge|2|2|10.77.132.170|stopped|vol-0b9390e079150ac1c|vol-0cd2df67aa096af52|vol-090c0d3290e1c4dad
i-0a6ef93417cc064eb|dr-psoft-app01|ami-09a868b800080436e|x86_64|Windows|z1d.xlarge|2|2|10.77.132.139|stopped|vol-00a5285f92f18b9ee|vol-0b979d1b578a1d672
```

I am expecting output as -

```
i-049c7aa5976d78ab3|dr-psoft-report01|ami-09a868b800080436e|x86_64|Windows|z1d.large|1|2|10.77.132.218|stopped|vol-07498f95efef04f85
i-05831bbd78bcfb9ac|dr-psoft-web01|ami-09a868b800080436e|x86_64|Windows|t3.xlarge|2|2|10.77.132.170|stopped|vol-0b9390e079150ac1c,vol-0cd2df67aa096af52,vol-090c0d3290e1c4dad
i-0a6ef93417cc064eb|dr-psoft-app01|ami-09a868b800080436e|x86_64|Windows|z1d.xlarge|2|2|10.77.132.139|stopped|vol-00a5285f92f18b9ee,vol-0b979d1b578a1d672
```

I am not sure where I am doing wrong. If anyone help me here, that will be great.

Comment: `join` needs an array as input. `…[] | [.]` creates a stream of multiple arrays. You want `[…[]]` (or just `…`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`((.VolID[]|[.])|join(","))` iterates all VolID values, then wraps each in an array with a single element. With a single element, there's nothing to join.

The input `{"VolID":[1,2,3]}` becomes `[1][2][3]` (a stream of elements). Instead, you want to collect all elements into an array, then join: `[.VolID[]]|join(",")`.

But now, if you look closely, `VolID` already is an array, so there's no sense in iterating and collecting again, just use the array directly: `.VolID|join(",")`. Also consider using `@csv` instead of `join(",")`. The `@csv` filter will handle escaping for you in case an array element contains a comma itself.

Other things I noticed which are unnecessary or too verbose:

```
jq -r '
.[]
| .[] # can be combined with previous filter
| [
.InstID, 
.Name, 
.ImageID, 
.Architecture, 
.OS, 
.InstType, 
(.CpuCore|tostring), # tostring not required for join
(.ThreadsPerCore|tostring), # tostring not required for join
.PrivIP, 
.Status, 
([(.VolID[]|.)]|join(":"))] # |. is a no-op, as is [.VolID[]]
| join("|")
'
```

Make that:

```
jq -r '
.[][]
| [.InstID, .Name, .ImageID, .Architecture, .OS, .InstType, .CpuCore, .ThreadsPerCore, .PrivIP, .Status, (VolID|join(":"))]
| join("|")
'
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining in detail where I was wrong. It was good learning. Just wanted to say only ```(.VolID[]|join(":"))``` is not working. I am getting error ```jq: error (at <stdin>:1919): Cannot iterate over string ("vol-07498f...)```. So I modified it to ```([.VolID[]]|join(":"))``` and it worked.

Comment: @BijiteshKundu yes, because it must be `(.VolID|join(":"))` – `.VolID` is an array already. `.VolID[]` is a stream of values. `[.whatever[]]` is identical to `.whatever` if you are dealing with an array. This is already in my answer: it shows `.VolID|join(",")` and _not_ `.VolID[]|join(",")`

Comment: Yeah - understood. Thanks again for taking time to explain why ```(.VolID|join(":"))``` will work. And it actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what I was doing wrong. The correct jq is -

```
jq -r '.[] | .[] | [.InstID, .Name, .ImageID, .Architecture, .OS, .InstType, (.CpuCore|tostring), (.ThreadsPerCore|tostring), .PrivIP, .Status, ([(.VolID[]|.)]|join(":"))] | join("|")'
```